# Yii2 check if a package is defined or not

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

In another Yii2 application I used a package called `navatech/yii2-roxymce` to replace the `textarea` with HTMl editable box. In the current application I don't want to use it while I want to keep everything easy reusable. In other words, I want a conditional check says that, if the package is installed call it, if not call the ordinary active form textarea.

I have tried `class_exists` like the following:

```
<?php
// _form.php code
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use navatech\roxymce\widgets\RoxyMceWidget;
......
<?php if (class_exists('RoxyMceWidget')): ?>
  <?= RoxyMceWidget::widget([
    'model'       => $model, //your Model, REQUIRED
    'attribute'   => 'content', //attribute name of your model, REQUIRED if using 'model' section
    'name'        => 'Post[content]', //default name of textarea which will be auto generated, NOT REQUIRED if using 'model' section
    'value'       => isset($_POST['Post']['content']) ? $_POST['Post']['content'] : $model->content, //default value of current textarea, NOT REQUIRED
    'action'      => Url::to(['roxymce/default']), //default roxymce action route, NOT REQUIRED
    'options'     => [//TinyMce options, NOT REQUIRED, see https://www.tinymce.com/docs/
        'title' => 'RoxyMCE',//title of roxymce dialog, NOT REQUIRED
        'height' => 450,
    ],

]);?>
  <?php else: ?> 
  <?= $form->field($model, 'content')->textarea(['rows' => 14]);?>
  <?php endif; ?>
.....
```

However, after the installation of `navatech\roxymce\widgets\RoxyMceWidget` using composer, the conditional statement gives the same result. i.e printing the ordinary activeform text area, so `class_exists` seems to always return false inspite off the widget is being installed.

Is there any other right way to check if a package is found or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide fully qualified namespace for the class.

```
class_exists('navatech\roxymce\widgets\RoxyMceWidget')
```

Comment: `class_exists` doesn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

with prs4 you must include namespace:

`class_exists('navatech\roxymce\widgets\RoxyMceWidget')`

or:

`class_exists(RoxyMceWidget::className())` if it already defined in the use statement.

---

updated: you should use lastest version of `yii2-roxymce`, current is `2.0.0.1`

Comment: The second solution of `className` is not complete solution. Suppose that the class in defined in the `use` but it is not installed. In this case an error message will be generated.

Comment: you're right. So `class_exists('navatech\roxymce\widgets\RoxyMceWidget')` is only solution